# How to change a Textview on other layout while living in viewPager in android

Tags: android

I want to change Textview on other layout while i am in other layout,below is my inflating layout.

```
rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sec_Page, container, false);
```

now i want to change a text view that on the topbar but not accessable through

```
((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1));
```

how I can access it?[image]

Comment: To clarify, you have a `ViewPager`, that contains `Fragment`s, and you want to update a `TextView` in (e.g.) `Fragment` two, by editing something in `Fragment` one. Is that correct? If so, do you have a fixed number of fragments in your `ViewPager`? Also, what is going to cause this change in `Fragment` two? (i.e. A button press)

Answer (score 0):

You can't 'change Textview on other layout', but you have individual fragments for each page. You have to recreate the fragment, not change it. So it's just a change of approach that is necessary.

"Change the text view" is a bit ambiguous, i'm not sure exactly what you mean. If you just mean the text in it, you could probably pass some information to the container activity & then when you change to the new fragment, this information is passed to the new fragment.

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter

There's a nice guide on there. I suggest you take a look. Sorry if i've missed the point here, found it hard to know what exactly you wanted.